# div layout format php

Tags: php, html, rows

i am trying it get that div displaying 5 in a row and then start a new line and display more

atm all that is happening is the are going under each other.

**CODE**

```
 < div>Line1< br />Line2< br>Line3< /div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Rephrase the question please and/or add the desired ouput.

Comment: There is a space char after each opening angle bracket. Is that intended? Code should be

<div>Line1<br/>Line2<br>Line3</div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want five divs side-by-side per line, the following works:

```
.cell { padding:0; margin:0; float:left; width:20%; }
.clear { clear:both; }
```

--

```
<div class="cell">1</div>
<div class="cell">2</div>
<div class="cell">3</div>
<div class="cell">4</div>
<div class="cell">5</div>
<div class="cell">6</div>
<div class="cell">7</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

For best results, all divs should have the same height. If they don't, you should place the `<div class="clear"></div>` after every 5<sup>th</sup> div.

Answer (score 0):

A `<br />` tag will always move to the beginning of the next line.  So if you had this (I took the liberty to add a "/" to your second br tag, maybe this was the problem):

```
<div>Line1<br />Line2<br />Line3</div>
```

You'd get this:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
```

Is that not what you want?  If not, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the divs to display side-by-side you'll need to use css floats to do that.

```
<style type="text/css">
div { float: left }
</style>
```

Then, you'll need to use a `<br clear="all" />` to move down to the next line.

This would mean that

```
<div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div>
```

Would show up as 12345 with the content all on the same line. Is this what you're looking for?